# Is there a secure drop available for Tor project?

Tags: anonymity, security, secure-drop

Does Tor project provide a secure drop facility available for interested parties to contact Tor project anonymously (the sender identity) and securely (the content of the message). If such a facility is available, where to find it? If not, is it being considered?

Answer (score 2):

No and No.

And I think the question is irrelevant to the site, since it's not about Tor, the software.

Also, I'm having a hard time picturing why Tor Project would need a 'secure-drop' instance. It's definitely not a news agency and 'secure-drop' isn't a messaging platform. Perhaps the question you want to ask is "How to disclose a bug privately and securely with Tor developers"? in that case, you can send a PGP encrypted email to one of the core developers from a pseudonym email account.

Answer (score 0):

No, Tor project does not provide such service. On the other hand, you can encrypt your email content using OpenPGP encryption, and use a hidden email service (such as mail2tor.com), that enables you to send emails to the clearnet, in order to hide your identity.

Comment: This is certainly disappointing. Many sites use Tor network to provide a user friendly, secure, and anonymous communication channel to their patrons for information exchange, but Tor does not provide this user friendly, secure, and anonymous channel to communicate with its patrons. Haleluya!!!!!