# Get Tor bridges via email

Tags: bridge

I sent an email to `bridges@bridges.torproject.org` with "get bridges" as the body by using my gmail. I didn't receive any response.

Is the service down? Is there something else I can do to get a list of bridges?

Comment: With regards to your concerns about the security of receiving bridges via email, please see this thread: https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/3511/does-using-email-to-send-bridges-and-pluggable-transport-bridges-hinder-anonymit

Comment: In an attempt to reproduce your missing reply email, I sent a mail requesting bridges a couple of hours ago (also from a Gmail account). I'm also yet to receive a response. Perhaps others who know more about this service can help, or, alternatively, you could send a quick mail to help@rt.torproject.org, as listed on [this](https://bridges.torproject.org/) page.

Comment: It seems there was a temporary problem with some component. However right now the service seems to work as expected.

Answer (score 6):

I always use this feature to get new bridges but the address is different. I send "get bridges" to **`bridges@torproject.org`**. Actually I sent one to be sure about my answer (**:D**). It is working perfectly.

Also you can get new bridges through [bridges.torproject.org](https://bridges.torproject.org/).

Answer (score 2):

COMMANDs: (combine COMMANDs to specify multiple options       simultaneously)

```
get bridges            Request vanilla bridges.
get transport [TYPE]   Request a Pluggable Transport by TYPE.
get help               Displays this message.
get key                Get a copy of BridgeDB's public GnuPG key.
get ipv6               Request IPv6 bridges.
```

Currently supported transport TYPEs:

```
    fte

    obfs3

    obfs4

    scramblesuit
```

---

> NOTE:The minimum time between
>   emails is 3 hours. All further emails during this time period will be ignored.
>
> ---

Example :

To:bridges@torproject.org

body: get bridges

**Send !**