# I can't install Tor, asking for bridge?

Tags: help, tor-install

Yesterday I may have accidentally deleted a file that Tor uses.  I tried to use Tor today and I tried to update it.  I am not able to install it at all now.  Here is the message I get "No provided bridges that have the transport type obfs4 are available. Please adjust your settings."  Please help.

Comment: Maybe this question can help: https://tor.stackexchange.com/q/7206/88

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link which gives some details as to bridges.  If you scroll down towards the bottom, it provides an email to receive bridges, and it shows you on this page how to add them. https://www.torproject.org/docs/bridges.html.en

Also, is there any reason why you can't remove your current instance of TorBrowserBundle, and reinstall another one? This will ensure at least that if you deleted an important script, you can still use TorBrowser correctly.