# Do secure channels provide a good means for asking bridges in order to stay annonymous

Tags: anonymity, security, email, bridge

After going through this post 
[Do utilization of bridges and/or Pluggable Transports bridges hinder anonymity?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/1430/do-utilization-of-bridges-and-or-pluggable-transports-bridges-hinder-anonymity) I ask is there any secure communication channel through which we can receive bridges as well as stay anonymous.

As asking for bridges through a normal mail is not viable I think there shall be a secure communication channel through which we can ask for bridges and provide anonymity to a certain extent.